# Property assignment expected.javascript when combined to jinja

Tags: javascript, python, visual-studio-code, flask, jinja2

Using javascript functions on one of my pages in flask, I need to use the jinja variables passed from python.

It actually works well but the thing is that VS Code shows me an error "Property assignment expected.javascript" on the brackets here :

```
{{ content|tojson }}
```

The current complete script is :

```
  function printData (nb) {
    const jsArrayOfItems = {{ content|tojson }};
    var str = JSON.stringify(jsArrayOfItems[nb][1], null, 2);
    document.write(str)
  }
```

with content a list passed from the python flask route.

I have already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468954/why-do-i-have-the-issue-property-assigment-expected-when-i-want-to-display-a-c) but it seems that I have the same problem than the author, which is that if I use quotation marks jsArrayOfItems becomes an empty value instead of the list.

So if you have any idea about how to avoid this problem I'd be glad someone tell me.
Thanks !

Comment: Modify `const jsArrayOfItems = {{ content|tojson }};` to `const jsArrayOfItems = {{ content|tojson|safe }};` or `const jsArrayOfItems = JSON.parse('{{ content|tojson|safe }}');
` and try to see if it works.

Comment: Hi @JialeDu, thanks a lot for your reply. The first solution was not working either because the problem was still there because of the curly brackets being outside of quotation marks. But the second one is currently perfectly working ! Thanks your a lot for this ! If you want maybe post it as an answer so that I can validate your answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the variable `content` is regarded as a string, and it is not converted into an effective JavaScript object. You can use the `json.parse()` function to parse the json string

Modify the code

```
const jsArrayOfItems = {{ content|tojson }};
```

to

```
const jsArrayOfItems = JSON.parse('{{ content|tojson|safe }}');
```