# Error Squiggles when using Jinja within an HTML script tag

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

https://imgur.com/a/S5XWNIB

The above link is a set of images that shows the error messages and the variables involved. Im using a Flask server backend where it renders an HTML template that also passes a python dictionary called

```
data
```

I want to convert this python dict into JSON and store it into a variable, where I pass it to set_homevalues(). The code works as intended even with the error squiggles, I'm just wondering how to remove them. Im using vs code.

I managed to find another post that has a similar problem: [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75663078/property-assignment-expected-javascript-when-combined-to-jinja)

I tried the solution and did

```
var jsvalid_data = JSON.parse('{{ data|tojson|safe }}')
set_homevalues(jsvalid_data)
```

But my code does not work after doing this, the following is an image of the console output: https://imgur.com/a/JdIT1ms